# How can I search the name or the email using ember-power-select

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I am using an addon called ember-power-select.

Github: https://github.com/cibernox/ember-power-select

Docs for search: https://ember-power-select.com/docs/the-search

Docs for Multiple select: https://ember-power-select.com/docs/multiple-selection/

Question: How can I search using `name` or `email`

`/template.hbs`

```
<PowerSelectMultiple
  @searchEnabled={{true}}
  @options={{this.authors}}
  @selected={{this.author}}
  @searchField="email"
  @placeholder="Select some names..."
  @onChange={{fn (mut this.author)}} as |author|>
  {{name}}
</PowerSelectMultiple>
```

`/controller.js`

```
 authors = [
    { name: 'Foo', email: 'foo@gmail.com' },
    { name: 'Bar', email: 'bar@gmail.com'},
    { name: 'Baz' email:  'baz@gmai.com'}
  ]
```

Answer (score 5):

```js
// controller .js

authors = [
    { name: 'Foo', email: 'foo@gmail.com' },
    { name: 'Bar', email: 'bar@gmail.com'},
    { name: 'Baz' email:  'baz@gmai.com'}
  ]
  
 // add below method you can do something like this
searchMethod(term) {
   let result = '';
   result = this.authors.filter((item)=>{
     if(term == item.name || term == item.email){
     return true;
   });
   return result;
  }
```

```html
/*template.hbs */

<PowerSelectMultiple
  @searchEnabled={{true}}
  @options={{this.authors}}
  @selected={{this.author}}
  @search={{this.searchMethod}}  /* add @search */
  @searchField="email"
  @placeholder="Select some names..."
  @onChange={{fn (mut this.author)}} as |author|>
  {{name}}
</PowerSelectMultiple>
```

[You can refer this link from Power-select DOC's](https://ember-power-select.com/docs/custom-search-action)

I am not sure about the return type of searchMethod , You can check power-select lib and customize it accordingly.

Comment: @Mikelemuel Consider accepting the answer if this answer solved your question